What really does and how to use the --uses param in a console when we use PHPUnit?
I came across with the param of PHPUnit while using a console.
How to use it and for what to use the param named --uses?
To concrete what I mean that the link to the doc:
https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.1/textui.html#:~:text=to%20document%20this.-,%2D%2Duses%20%3Cname%3E,-Only%20run%20tests
A enormous thanks to you if you help to reveal the gist of that.

You can specify to run only tests using that specific classname you pass. Alternatively you can use the Atttribute UsesClass for code coverage.

I have found it at https://manpages.debian.org/testing/phpunit/phpunit.1.en.html
It says:
Only runs tests annotated with "@uses <name>"

So, let's suppose that your name is Monkey. In that case you can annotate tests with
/**
 * @covers \BankAccount
 * @uses   \Money
 */
public function testMoneyCanBeDepositedInAccount(): void
{
    // ...
}


The @uses annotation specifies code which will be executed by a test, but is not intended to be covered by the test. A good example is a value object which is necessary for testing a unit of code.

It has another example here: https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.5/code-coverage.html#code-coverage-targeting-units-of-code-examples-invoicetest-php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\CoversClass;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Attributes\UsesClass;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

#[CoversClass(Invoice::class)]
#[UsesClass(Money::class)]
final class InvoiceTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testAmountInitiallyIsEmpty(): void
    {
        $this->assertEquals(new Money, (new Invoice)->amount());
    }
}

